# How to extract from and render data from one JSON object into a flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a an that requests a customer and their details from an API server. This the response that gets sent back :

```
{
    "cust_id": 1,
    "given_name": "John",
    "family_name": "Smith",
    "email": "smith99@hotmail.com",
    "recent_purchases": [
        {
            "item_id": 1,
            "price": 20,
            "item_descr": "Small apple”
        },
        {
            "item_id ": 2,
            " price ": 15,
            "item_descr": "Sponge Cake”
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

This is my get GET function that gets the response and stores it in :

custDetails: [] state

```
getCustDetails () {
      return fetch(‘API URL HERE’,  
         {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
         })
         .then((res) => res.json())
         .then((resJson) => {
            this.setState({
               custDetails: resJson,
            });
            console.log("The server response is :" + this.state.userDetail)
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
         });
   }
```

But when I try render the customer details in a flatlist, nothing appears and no error appear. 
The log message that appears from the getCust function:
"The server response is :[object Object]"

My flatlist set up:

```
       <FlatList
           data={this.state.custDetails}
           keyExtractor={({ cust_id}) => cust_id}
           renderItem={({ cust}) => <View style={styles.list}>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{cust.cust_id }</Text>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{cust.given_name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{cust.family_name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{cust.email}</Text>
           </View>}
        />
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: did you check your current ```state```?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to iterate over a plain object. If the server response is

```
{
    "cust_id": 1,
    "given_name": "John",
    "family_name": "Smith",
    "email": "smith99@hotmail.com",
    "recent_purchases": [
        {
            "item_id": 1,
            "price": 20,
            "item_descr": "Small apple”
        },
        {
            "item_id ": 2,
            " price ": 15,
            "item_descr": "Sponge Cake”
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

your setState should be

```
this.setState({
    custDetails: [resJson],
});
```

You console logs `[object Object]` because you have to use `JSON.stringify`.

```
console.log("The server response is :" + JSON.stringify(this.state.userDetail))
```